# neutralization of a strong acid with a strong base

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration

When a 1M H2SO4 is mixed with an equal volume of 1M NaOH, is the mixture acidic, basic, or neutral?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Please note that formulas can be better expressed with \$\ce{}\$ for chemical formulas/equations, \$\mathrm{}\$ for math term/equations, and \$\pu\$ for units. More information is available in [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3044/23561) Also, take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sulfuric acid is diprotic, the reaction of sulfuric acid with sodium hydroxide has a 1:2 ratio, with twice as much sodium hydroxide being used up in the reaction. The neutralization reaction would be:

$\ce{H2SO4 + 2NaOH -> Na2SO4 + 2H2O}$

After that reaction is complete, approximately half of the sulfuric acid remains, and you would be left with an acidic solution.

Edit: As was pointed out below, I failed to balance my sodium hydroxide.

Comment: Balance sodium hydroxide :$\ce{2NaOH}$

Comment: Since hydroxide ion is a monoprotic base and sulphuric acid is a diprotic acid
, there are actually two equations involved.
Because we have an equimolar amount of acid and base, the products of the first reaction are sodium bisulfate and water;-
$$\ce{H2SO4 + NaOH -> NaHSO4 + H2O}$$